# How to upgrade from Magento 1.8.0.0 to 2.0.0.0?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-2.0

I am going to do version up gradation in Magento, first-time. Anybody can help me please?
This time, my Magento version is 1.8.0.0 and I want to upgrade this in version 2.0. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. 
The final version of Magento 1 is 1.9.2.2 and Magento 2 is a brand new platform.

Comment: Hi DangHiep! there is no way to upgrade this? Any Idea?

Comment: No, you can't. You have to build your website from beginning. As I know, Magento provide tools to migrate products and customers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can upgrade from Magento 1.x to 2.x, but it is primarily about upgrading your data.  It would ridiculous if there wasn't a migration path.  I think those say "no, you can't" mean that any code isn't automatic.  If you have a custom theme or extensions, those won't work on 2.x, you'll need to adopt/customize a new theme and extensions on 2.x.